# Why does DNN always add a banner module when I try to add an HTML module?

Tags: dotnetnuke

If I try to add an HTML module to a page in DotNetNuke 7.4.2 it always adds a banner module.

This has been happened since upgrading from 6.x to 7.x.

It appears like once you select the module you want in the combo box and hit add module, the combos reset to the first index which happens to be a banner module.

Comment: Sounds like a potentially buggy upgrade. You might try changing the Control Panel option to "toolbar" in the host settings to see if that helps you get around it until you are able to track down the ultimate cause.

Comment: Thanks Chris, I'll try that, but I think the current skin I'm using requires the Ribbonbar to be used for some reason.  I've been doing upgrades on this site since 3.x so you are probably right I've got baggage from all those previous versions.  I wish there was an easy way to import this site into a fresh install of the current version.

Comment: Changing to ControlBar from Ribbonbar did the trick!